# Problema com ALOCAÇÂO DINÂMICA com ponteiro de char em structs

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, alocação

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Devo criar um programa que irá cadastrar um número N de alunos e o tamanho maximo do nome de cada aluno é M.
Devo usar a seguinte estrutura:

```
struct Aluno{
  int matricula;
  char *nome;
};
```

E devo implementar as funções:

```
Aluno* aloca_vetor_alunos(int tamanho_vetor, int tamanho_nome);

void libera_memoria_alunos(int tamanho_vetor, Aluno* alunos);
```

Para criar o vetor de alunos devo utilizar alocação dinâmica de memória. Com isso, fiz o seguinte código:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Aluno{
    int matricula;
    char *nome;
};

struct Aluno* aloca_vetor_alunos(int tamanho_vetor, int tamanho_nome){
    struct Aluno* ptr1;

    ptr1 = (struct Aluno*) malloc(sizeof(struct Aluno) * tamanho_vetor);
    ptr1->nome = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * tamanho_nome);

    return ptr1;
}

void libera_memoria_alunos(int tamanho_vetor, struct Aluno* alunos){

}

int main(){
    int N, M;
    int i;
    struct Aluno* alunos;

    printf("Quantos alunos serao cadastrados? ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Tamanho maximo do nome? ");
    scanf("%d", &M);

    alunos = aloca_vetor_alunos(N, M);

    for(i = 0; i < N+1; i++){
        printf("Matricula: ");
        scanf("%d", &alunos[i].matricula);
        printf("Nome: ");
        scanf("%s", alunos[i].nome);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("%d - %d", i, alunos[i].matricula);
        printf("%d - %s", i, alunos[i].nome);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Contudo, estou enfrentando problemas na hora de ler e printar os dados. O programa só lê 2 alunos e depois fecha e não printa os dados.

Comment: Qual o sentido deste `N+1` em `for(i = 0; i < N+1; i++){`? Outro ponto: se você especificou um tamanho máximo para o nome (`M`) então creio que deveria limitar o tamanho dos nomes informados.

Comment: Acho que escrevi o (+1) por engano.  E quanto a limitação dos nomes, acredito que já fiz isso quando aloco memória para o nome não?

Comment: Não, o scanf pode avançar além da memória alocada.

Comment: Entendi. Vou tentar aqui, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o trecho de código abaixo aloca memória para apenas o ponteiro `nome` do primeiro elemento do vetor.

```
ptr1->nome = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * tamanho_nome);
```

O certo seria iterar por todos elementos e alocar para cada um. Como embaixo:

```
ptr1 = (struct Aluno*) malloc(sizeof(struct Aluno) * tamanho_vetor);

for(int i = 0; i < tamanho_vetor; i++)
{
    ptr1[i].nome = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * tamanho_nome);
}
```

Poderia também usar a função `fgets` para limitar o tamanho de entrada do nome.

```
fgets(alunos[i].nome, M, stdin);
```

Comment: Nossa, não tinha pensado nisso. Verifiquei aqui e deu certo. Obrigado!!

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar como aceite caso a resposta foi útil.